# Filtering from large dataset in a stream processing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, apache-storm, flink-streaming, stream-processing

I'm working on a streaming application, the input stream is a series of events. For each event, I need to filter out the valid subscribers from relational database.

`eventId => (eventId, [subscriberIds])`

Suppose the subscription table is bounded(or unbounded if convenient), and have millions of rows, is there a way to do this filtering efficiently?

Suppose I'm using Flink, but I'm also open for Spark or Storm solutions.

Comment: So, You have table that maps eventId or eventType to valid `subscriberId` ?? And You want to use this to filter out the ones that are not valid ?

Comment: Yeah, it's a subscription table, records event subscription status. @DominikWosiński

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the set of valid subscribers is constantly being updated, and that you mustn't use out-of-date information in performing this validation, then Flink offers a couple of choices:

1. Use Flink's async i/o operator to manage queries to the relational database
2. Maintain a mirror of the relational database in Flink state by streaming in its change data capture stream

Comment: I'm interested in the 2nd option, could it be more performant than the option 1?

Comment: btw, I stumbled across this http://apache-flink.147419.n8.nabble.com/Filter-with-large-key-set-td1557.html, which looks a lot like what I'm dealing with now.

Comment: Do you think if it feasible to use a BroadCastStream, to broadcast the subscription stream to the event stream for the lookup?

Comment: Yeah, generally if the table won't be very big the second solution could easily use the broacastStream and then prerform lookup in the process function.

Comment: The potential issue with broadcast state is that it cannot use RocksDB, so it must live on the heap, and each instance will checkpoint its copy of it -- so for those reasons, you don't want it to be too large.